# Adding a security questions in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I add a challenge question to existing challenge set ot create new challenge question set from IS 5.3.0 carbon console, and when I invoke the "getAllChallengeQuestions" operation in
UserIdentityManagementAdminService, it  returns the only old set of challenge question. The newly added ones are not visible.

And also , when I add a new question using the "setChallengeQuestions" in admin service, its get added, and I could not see this newly added question in carbon console as well. And also If I invoke the "getAllChallengeQuestions" method after adding a challenge question, it only shows me the newly added one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some changes in some of the feature implementations since 5.3.0. Therefore, you can not use `UserIdentityManagementAdminService` to manage challenge questions since 5.3.0.

You can use `ChallengeQuestionManagementAdminService` instead.

- getChallengeQuestionsOfTenant
- setChallengeQuestionsOfTenant